# Generate random integer in MIPS which compiles with QtSpim

Tags: random, mips, qtspim

So I've seen a lot of questions on generating random integers in a MIPS program using MARS and **syscall 42** and that's ok. The problem is that I need to generate a random integer for a program compiled with **QtSpim**, which has no syscall for 42 or however for calls greater than 17. 
I can't figure out getting something like a random value from the system like syscall 30 in MARS which gives the system time.

Is there a way to get a random address or hex value to use for a random int generator using xor operations ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can create a simple pseudo-random number generator by implementing [a linear-feedback shift register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register).

Comment: Could you please give me an example of MIPS code doing it?

Comment: Implement it in C or Java (or some other language that you're more familiar with) first, then transcribe it to MIPS assembly.

Comment: You want the random seed or the random generator?